# Can't update the database after click on the submit button in servlet jsp

Tags: servlets

I can't update the database after clicking on the submit button in servlet jsp.

**index.jsp**

```
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.DriverManager"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <% 
    try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/xigmapro","root","");
        Statement st=con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs1=st.executeQuery("select * from user_information");
%>
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td width="120">User Name</td><td width="120">User Address</td>
            <td width="120">User City</td><td width="120">User State</td>
            <td width="120">User Mail</td><td width="120">User Phone</td>
            <td width="120">User Post</td><td width="120">User Country</td>
            <td width="120">Action</td>
        </tr>
      <%
     while(rs1.next())
        {
         String uid=rs1.getString("client_id");
         out.println(uid);
    %>
            <tr><td width="120"><% out.print(rs1.getString("client_name"));%></td><td
    width="120"><% out.print(rs1.getString("client_address")); %></td><td width="120">
    <% out.print(rs1.getString("client_city")); %></td>
            <td width="120"><% out.print(rs1.getString("client_state")); %></td><td
    width="120"><% out.print(rs1.getString("client_mail")); %></td>
            <td width="120"><% out.print(rs1.getString("client_phone")); %></td><td
    width="120"><% out.print(rs1.getString("client_post")); %></td><td width="120"><%
    out.print(rs1.getString("client_country")); %></td>
            <td width="190"><form action="NewServlet" method="post">

                    <input type="hidden" name="uid" value="<%=uid %>"/>
                    <input type="submit" name="send" value="Update">

            </form>||<form action="NewServlet" method="post">
                    <input type="hidden" name="uid" value="<%=uid %>"/>
                    <input type="submit" name="send" value="Delete">
                </form></td>
           </tr>
         <%

          }%>
</table>
   <%
   }catch(Exception e)
  {
    out.println(e);
  }
        %>
    </body>
</html>
```

**NewSevlet.java**

```
import java.awt.Choice;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.sql.*;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Connection;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import org.apache.catalina.Session;

public class NewServlet extends HttpServlet {

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        try {
        } catch (Exception e) {
            out.println(e);
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);

        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        String Uid = request.getParameter("uid");
        String choice = request.getParameter("send");

        try {

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/xigmapro",
                    "root", "");

            Statement st = con.createStatement();

            if (choice.equals("Add")) {
                String uid = request.getParameter("uid");

                out.println(uid);

                Statement st1 = con.createStatement();
                st1.executeUpdate("UPDATE user_information SET" + "`client_name`='" + request.getParameter("user_name") + "',`client_address`='" + request.getParameter("user_add") + "',`client_city`='" + request.getParameter("user_city") + "'WHERE `client_id`=uid");

//response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
                out.println("UPDATE user_information SET " + "`client_name`='" + request.getParameter("user_name") + "',`client_address`='" + request.getParameter("user_add") + "',`client_city`='" + request.getParameter("user_city") + "' WHERE `client_id`='uid'");
            }

            if (choice.equals("Delete")) {
                st.executeUpdate("delete from user_information where `client_id`='" + Uid + "'");
                out.println("user deleted from database successfully");
//RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("next.jsp");
//rd.include(request, response);
            }

            if (choice.equals("Update")) {
                PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT *FROM xigmapro.user_information WHERE client_id =  ?");
                ps.setString(1, Uid);

                ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

                if (rs.next()) {
                    String UID = rs.getString("client_id");
                    out.println(UID);
                    out.println("<form action='' method='post'>");
                    out.println("<input type='hidden' name='uid' value = '" + rs.getString("client_id") + "' / >");
                    out.println("<table border='1' width='280px' height='120px'>");
                    out.println("<tr width='280px'><td width='180'>User Name</td><td  width='120'>User Address</td > <td width = '180'>User City</td > <td width = '180'>User State</td >" + "<td  width='120'>User Mail</td><td  width='180'>User Phone</td><td  width='120'>User Country</td > < / tr >");
                    out.println("<tr><td>");
                    out.print("<input type='text' name='user_name' value = '" + rs.getString("client_name") + "' / >" + " < /td>");
                    out.print("<td>" + "<input type='text' name='user_add' value = '" + rs.getString("client_address") + "' / >" + " < /td>");
                    out.print("<td>" + "<input type='text' name='user_city' value = '" + rs.getString("client_city") + "' / >" + " < /td>");
                    out.print("<td>" + "<input type='text' name='user_state' value = '" + rs.getString("client_state") + "' / >" + " < /td>");
                    out.print("<td>" + "<input type='text' name='user_mail' value = '" + rs.getString("client_mail") + "' / >" + " < /td>");
                    out.print("<td>" + "<input type='text' name='user_phone' value = '" + rs.getString("client_phone") + "' / >" + " < /td>");
                    out.print("<td>" + "<input type='text' name='user_contry' value = '" + rs.getString("client_country") + "' / >" + " < /td>");
                    out.print("</td></tr>");
                    out.println("</td></tr></table>");
                    out.println("<input type='submit' name='send' value='Add'>");
                    out.println("</form>");
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }
}
```

I have created the database successfully, connection to the database also successful. But when I click on the "Add" button of `NewSevlet.java` page it can't update the table. After click on the "Add" submit button, I can see particular user ID which I send as hidden field, but it can't update the table. Also my query is OK. `Index.jsp` is first page and `NewServlet.java` is the second page.

Comment: Start by adding e.printStackTrace(); inside your catch blocks to see if there are exceptions

Comment: Jezz f&*¨$3 christ. Empty catch blocks break open the gates of hell. Don't you ever, ever leave them empty, unless you wanna burn!!

Comment: I voted to close as the OP does not provide further details (stacktraces, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

You missed spaces after `SET` and before `WHERE` in this line: `st1.executeUpdate("UPDATE user_information...`

```
SET" + " `client_name`
"' WHERE
```

And I strong recommend to validate all input data and use prepared statement.